# How to define default values with Entity Framework C#?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, model

Models in question:

```
public class EmployeeType
{
    public int employeeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string typeName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public int employeeTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployeeType EmployeeTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment i am adding different values through:

```
db.EmployeeType.Add(new EmployeeType
{
    typeName = "Administrator"
});
db.EmployeeType.Add(new EmployeeType
{
    typeName = "Seller"
});
db.EmployeeType.Add(new EmployeeType
{
    typeName = "Accountant"
});
```

But in a case when i have to check if the user is an administrator or etc. i have to check through linq query and find out if the id is equal to the id in the Employee table.

How could i define default records in the EmployeeType model and not add the values through multiple .Add lines, so that i could use something like this:

```
if (db.Employee.FirstOrDefault(o => ...).servictypeId 
== EmployeeType.Administrator)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this would be to convert employeetypeId into an enum in EF. You can easily achieve this by "converting" the field into an enum within the EDMX. Just right click on the property in the edmx model design screen and click "convert to enum".

Firstly though, you need to create an Enum, Called UserRole :-

```
enum UserRole : int
{
    Administrator = 1,
    Manager = 2,
    Client = 3

}
```

Now, when you want to make new UserRole's you add them in your Enum.

When it comes to adding a new user, you simply do the following :-

```
new User object1 { Name = "Fred", UserRole = UserRole.Client};

dbContext.Save(object1);
```

EF will know to save the employeeTypeId as 3 in the database.

The advantage gets better, because now you can say :-

```
if(User.UserRole == UserRole.Adminstartor)
{
  //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: [Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh1m2o2apv2wamj/edmxpic.jpg)
Here is my situation.
Actually it is the first time im doing something with edmx, because i usually used classes in order to use entity framework. I dont understand the concept of converting the employeetypeId if it is in a class not the edmx. Could you refer me to an article, which describes what you are trying to teach me. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i believe that when you ment "The best way to handle this would be to convert employeetypeId into an enum in EF.", it would mean to change from code first datbase designing to EDMX. That would have ment, that i had to make my whole model structure again through EDMX. So i didnt just understand why did you mention that i had to use EDMX, but your solution further worked perfectly. :)